# Find $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})$ where $f(\mathbf{x}) = || A\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} ||^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})$, where $f(\mathbf{x}) = || A\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} ||^2$. $\mathbf{b}$ is a constant vector. I know that the answer is $2A^\top(A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})$, but I want to derive the solution. I, however, am stuck and have no clue how to proceed. Here's my work so far

First I rewrite $f(\mathbf{x})$ as $$ f(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i,j}(a_{ij}x^j-b^j)^2\quad.$$ Then I write $$ \begin{align} \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) &= \sum_k \partial_{x^k}f(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{e}_k\\ &= \sum_k\sum_{i,j}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x^k}(a_{ij}x^j-b^j)^2\mathbf{e}_k \end{align} $$ here we can drop the index $k$ since we will get zero if $k\neq j$. Thus we have $$ \begin{align} \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) &= \sum_{i,j} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x^j}(a_{ij}x^j-b^j)^2\mathbf{e}_j\\ &= \sum_{i,j}2a_{ij}(a_{ij}x^j-b^j)\mathbf{e}_j \end{align}$$ but here's where I'm stuck. If I could invert the indexes in the first $a_{ij}$, I think I would get the desired result, but I don't know if I could do that. And even if I could, I wouldn't know why it would be correct. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule to compute the Jacobian matrix $Df(x)$, then use $\nabla f(x) = Df(x)^T$. We have
$$Df(x) = 2(Ax - b)^TA,$$
so
$$\nabla f(x) = 2A^T(Ax - b).$$